# My Email Server is rejecting incoming mail

Tags: windows, email, smtp, windows-server-2008

I've got a Windows 2008 Web Server and have just installed Smartermail Mail Server Software.

The server will send messages but the replies bounce back.

I have attached my dns entries

[image: dns entries]

Ports 25 and 110 are open on the server.

Any ideas where to start next.

Thanks

John

Comment: Sorry, didnt realise i'd posted in the wrong place.

The messages says:

"This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

username@domain.com"

The username does exist!!

Comment: So it is reaching the server (else it could not reply with that message) so it seems user xxx at xxx@yourcomain.com is not configured within smartermail as a recipient/user

Comment: the account does exist because I can logon to the account and successfully send an email.

Comment: As sorry, I misread that as *The username does not exist*

Comment: @John Please update your question when you have new details: that's the way to do it here. In order to answer your question, it would be useful to have the full content of the bounce message as well as the log of the sending mail server for that message (if you have them). Also, if you have the log of the server's end of the connection, that might be of help.

Comment: Heres the detailed error message:

"Reporting-MTA: dns;dub0-omc4-s16.dub0.hotmail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;DUB119-W29
Arrival-Date: Wed, 5 Jun 2013 05:51:50 -0700

Final-Recipient: rfc822;username@domain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for username@domain.com"

Comment: @JohnMoore If an answer below helped you resolve your issue, tick the big tick mark next to it, and optionally, upvote the answer.  This gives everyone a warm and fuzzy feeling, and gives reputation to the owner of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP Error 571 is usually a sub portion of SMTP Error 550.
So typically you will get an “SMTP Error 550 571” or an
“SMTP Error 550 5.7.1”. SMTP Error 571 is ussually the recipient’s server telling your sending
server that “it has been told not to work with you !”.

How is your IIS server setup to authenticate? Also, you may need to grab the IIS logs per stephanie's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to relay for username@domain.com"

This typically means that your email server thinks you're trying to use it as a relay to send email to the recipient... because your email server isn't configured to be authoritative for the recipient domain. You may have the user account set up but do you have the domain configured on the server and do you have the server configured as authoritative for the domain? It's likely that it isn't and you need to configure the server to be authoritative for the domain.

Comment: [Resolved] in the smtp-in settings in Smartermail the smtp banner was set to #hostname#. I thought this was a system variable. I have changed it to my domain and it now works. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks for all the advice. I've learnt alot